# Managing Context in Dialogflow

Tags: spring, dialogflow-es

I want to know if the context of the conversation can be maintained in Dialog-flow like for example:

**User:** Total cost

**Bot:** Total cost for which Account:

```
 1.ABC
 2.XYZ
 3.PQR
```

**User:** Clicks the account name

**Bot:** Total cost for ABC is ####(some amount)

**User:** I want to know more

**Bot:** Previous Month total cost was ####, this month is ****

This way the context is to be maintained. But as I see the documents the context can be maintained only till two conversational flow. Is there any way that I can follow to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the lifespan of the context either in the DialogFlow agent UI, or via the API.

See https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-input-output#lifespan for the description of context lifespan.  As you mention, the default lifespan for each context is 2 conversational units, but you can modify this to any number as you see fit. See the following image as an example.

[image: DialogFlow output context]

It is also referenced in the API documentation here:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.contexts#Context.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a hard limit on the lifespan number. Meaning, if you want the context to remain active for the full 20 minutes, you can set it to an arbitrarily high number such as 1000. However, I would not recommend you do this. I would try to nail down exactly how you want the conversation to flow and manage your context with more fine grained lifespans.

Comment: @RoopikaChari - if an answer has helped, upvoting and/or accepting the answer is always appreciated. Click on the up-arrow to upvote, and the checkmark to accept it as an answer that has addressed your question.